# Jordan normal form book

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, jordan-normal-form

I am currently reading the book **Basic Algebra [modern] Anthony W. Knapp** about Jordan canonical form

Is there any detailed oriented book about **Jordan Normal Form** which explain :

- An Algorithm to put a matrix in Jordan normal form.
- How to Find Bases for Jordan Canonical Forms ( i think there is lots but one which universal based on proof  )
- an Examples of how to find a matrix P that puts A in JCF

any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Hoffman and Kunze's Linear Algebra explains Jordan Normal Form quite extensively, with examples and all. It doesn't talk about algorithms for finding it though.

Answer (score 1):

Try Weintraub [*Jordan Canonical Form Theory and Practice*](https://books.google.it/books?id=qDPMLisVSCIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Jordan+Canonical+Form+Theory+and+Practice&hl=it&sa=X&ei=423iVMq5JYXWaoSngugE&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Jordan%20Canonical%20Form%20Theory%20and%20Practice&f=false). It seems quite detailed.